# How do you combine many audio tracks into one for mediaRecorder API?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediarecorder, web-audio-api

I want to make a recording where, I get multiple audio tracks from different mediaStream objects (some of them, remote). Use the getAudioTracks () method and add them to a mediaStream object using addTrack (). At the moment of passing this last object as a parameter for mediaRecorder I realize that it only records the audio track located in position [0]. That gives me to understand that mediaRecorder is capable of recording a track by type, is there any way to join these tracks into one to record them correctly using mediaRecorder? I would be grateful for any page that explains this if possible and if it exists

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 20):

I was battling with this for a while and took me ages to realise that the MediaStream only ever recorded the first track I added. My solution was to get the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) involved. This example uses two UserMedia (e.g. a mic & Stereo Mix) and merges them. The UserMedia are identified by their `deviceId` as shown when you use `await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`.

In summary:

- Create an `AudioContext()`
- Get your media using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`
- Add these as a stream source to the AudioContext
- Create an AudioContext stream destination object
- Connect your sources to this single destination
- And your new MediaRecorder() takes this destination as its MediaStream

Now you can record yourself singing along to your favourite song as it streams ;)

```js
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
audioParams_01 = {
    deviceId: "default",
}
audioParams_02 = {
    deviceId: "7079081697e1bb3596fad96a1410ef3de71d8ccffa419f4a5f75534c73dd16b5",
}

mediaStream_01 = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: audioParams_01 });
mediaStream_02 = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: audioParams_02 });

audioIn_01 = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream_01);
audioIn_02 = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream_02);

dest = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

audioIn_01.connect(dest);
audioIn_02.connect(dest);

const recorder = new MediaRecorder(dest.stream);

chunks = [];

recorder.onstart = async (event) => {
    // your code here
}

recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {       
    chunks.push(event.data); 
}

recorder.onstop = async (event) => {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: And for @MickaelFM's comment to a previous answer _"How can you add a track while recording?"_, in my use case (which is a bit more than the basic code above) I automatically stop and then restart the recording. The new recorder object uses the audio inputs as defined by my settings. There is a 'blip' in the audio listening back, so not perfectly smooth, but it works.

Comment: Awesome! I knew the audio API was going to be involved, in short this is a solution

Comment: @lucasemanuelhimelfarb You should select it as the solution then. A little green check mark just to the left side.

Comment: Hi Adam, can you please elaborate a bit more on how you stopped and restarted and managed both streams, how did you know when to trigger the stop in one stream and start in another. I am only able to figure out that I need to record both the streams separately and then once processed to wav, can merge them.

Comment: Hi @Plasmatiger. My solution may be quite specific to my needs. So if we assume a user has selected to add an additional media stream while already recording, an event handler attached to my audio selection UI kicks off the following: [1] stop and close any current recordings & ```audioContext.close();``` [2] create a ```new AudioContext();``` with both sources, [3] start a new recording. This results in 2 seperate recordings which I tie together in my playback functionality with custom info stating the relationship between the two recordings. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @AdamMarsh, thanks for the prompt reply. Will go through your advice and get back if needed. You are real help :)

Comment: My app is written using electron. I have just noticed that ```navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()``` includes video too, and this kicks off a "... trying to access your webcam" alert for some Anti-virus software. Have you guys noticed this? If your project is run in a browser, do you get an equivalent message? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68051743

Comment: Life saver, thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I could give you more than one upvote! :D

Answer (score 5):

Finish using a library built by muazKhan, which allows you to merge the streams and return them in one!

It's incredibly easy!

https://github.com/muaz-khan/MultiStreamsMixer

Comment: But once it is setup, you can not change anything, right ? How can you add a track while recording ? MediaRecorder does not allow that

Comment: You should have added some code to your answer.

Comment: But very helpful on my case