# How I can merge two audio files - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webrtc, record, video-conferencing

I have two audio files from `RecordRTC` both local & remote streams. Now I want to merge the two files into one file and upload it to the server via AJAX.

> e.g. *(audio1.webm)* and *(audio2.webm)*.

```
mediaRecorder.stopRecording(function() {
    var blob = mediaRecorder.getBlob();
    var fileName = getFileName('webm');

    var fileObject = new File([blob], fileName, {
        type: 'audio/webm'
    });

    var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('blob', fileObject);
        formData.append('filename', fileObject.name);

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('/') }}/save-audio',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

I made it this way instead of `recorder.addStreams`, and still I can get the recorded.

```
var remoteVideos = $('#remoteVideos video');
var el = [];

$.each($('#remoteVideos video'), function(index, val) {
     el[index] = val.srcObject;
});
el.push(stream);
multiMediaRecorder = new MultiStreamRecorder(el);
```

Comment: when you say merge, do you mean concatenate the two audio files, or combine them in a different way?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to combine them because the audio files contain a conversation. _e.g._ `audio1` asks the question then `audio2` gives the answer.

Comment: I have try the `ffmpeg` only in my local, but how can I configure it on live server?

Comment: FYI, A similar question here where answers take a different tack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165335/how-do-you-combine-many-audio-tracks-into-one-for-mediarecorder-api/62336773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar library: [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder). Then use **MultiStreamRecorder** and pass two streams as below,

```
recorder = new MultiStreamRecorder([localStream, remoteStream]);
```

You will get localStream from getUserMedia and remoteStream from onaddstream event listener.

You may want to just pass the audio tracks in the array. The rest of the things as it is. FFmpeg and file merging is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you @ishan, but I'm little confuse on how can I detect if it is localStream and remoteStream?

Comment: Can you help me sir? I'm stuck on this problem. I am new in javascript and also to this library.

Comment: The stream you get in getUserMedia method is your localStream and the one you get in onaddstream listener is your remoteStream.

Comment: Is it okay to use this code to get remoteStreams `$('#remoteVideos video')[0]`. Maximum of 8 remotestreams.

Comment: Oh, my bad. What is the best approach for this? using `addStreams`? can you have give sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now by doing this, as below;

```
function onMediaSuccess(localStream) {

            var remoteVideos = $('#remoteVideos video')[0];
            multiMediaRecorder = new MultiStreamRecorder([localStream, remoteVideos.srcObject]);
            multiMediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
                // POST/PUT "Blob" using FormData/XHR2
                var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                console.log(blobURL);
            };
            multiMediaRecorder.start();
    }
```

But now there's another problem, `ondataavailable` is called twice but the first video is playable and working properly, while the second video is playable but *(less than one second)* I think it might be corrupted.

Cheers!

Comment: Use a variable instead. Declare an array of blobs and push into it when you get data. Like, 
recorder.ondataavailable = blob => recordedBlobs.push(blob);

Comment: Okay, thank you.. then I want to upload it to my server via ajax. Is it okay to call it inside the `ondataavailable` function?

Comment: Yes, it is fine. Please accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: Hi @ishanshah, after I save the blob on the server, it's playable but when I refresh the videocall, it not working anymore it says `Your file was not found (It may have been moved or deleted)`