# How can we concat two audios into one single audio?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have two audio URLs(mp3). I want to concat these two audio into one single audio and use it in an HTML audio tag.

I have tried using `window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext` Web API.

Here,

```js
/**
 * Function to concatenate audio files from URLs and return a new URL later use in HTML audio tag
 */
async concatenateAudioFiles(urls) {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext()

    // Fetch all audio files and decode them as audio buffers
    const audioBuffers = await Promise.all(
        urls.map((url) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
                request.open('GET', url, true)
                request.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
                request.onload = () => {
                    audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response, resolve, reject)
                }
                request.send()
            })
        })
    )

    // Create a new audio buffer with the combined length of all audio buffers
    const outputAudioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(
        audioBuffers[0].numberOfChannels,
        audioBuffers[0].length,
        audioBuffers[0].sampleRate
    )

    // Copy the audio buffers into the new audio buffer
    for (let channel = 0; channel < outputAudioBuffer.numberOfChannels; channel++) {
        const outputData = outputAudioBuffer.getChannelData(channel)
        for (let bufferIndex = 0; bufferIndex < audioBuffers.length; bufferIndex++) {
            const inputData = audioBuffers[bufferIndex].getChannelData(channel)
            for (let sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < audioBuffers[bufferIndex].length; sampleIndex++) {
                outputData[sampleIndex] += inputData[sampleIndex]
            }
        }
    }

    // Create a new audio URL from the audio buffer
    const outputAudioURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([outputAudioBuffer], { type: 'audio/*' }))

    return outputAudioURL // Return the audio URL
}
```

But the URL I got is not working.

When I try to play the out then it's working.

```js
// Play the output audio
const source = audioContext.createBufferSource()
source.buffer = outputAudioBuffer
source.connect(audioContext.destination)
source.start()
```

How can I get a working URl?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60222074/how-i-can-merge-two-audio-files-javascript

Comment: @SureshKamrushi I searched on Google. Even I searched on stack overflow. But did find the solution.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Have you found anything else?

Comment: Ignore JavaScript, it's rubbish. Do this on the backend using `ffmpeg` and `shell`.

Comment: @MattKomarnicki Yes, you are right. But I have to do it form the front-end side.