# Electron app using navigator.mediaDevices triggers antivirus "Webcam access attempt"

Tags: javascript, electron, webapi, mediadevices

I have developed an electron app and for the first time ever, my antivirus (ESET) has raised "Webcam access attempt" when the app loads. Has anyone else experienced this?

My app does not use the webcam and I have no code that requires the webcam.

I do have code that accesses audio for audio recording. I have denied access to the webcam in antivirus and the app does function as designed. However, antivirus warning messages appear on every load of the app. As you can imagine, this is not cool.

This has surfaced immediately after updating ESET (v14.2.10.0), so they have some new rule that gets triggered. I have to assume that this is not an ESET over sensitivity to something (I have no idea how AV's function and ‘blaming’ the antivirus doesn’t seem like a sound response to provide users), so I am left questioning my deployment of web-apis in my code.

My audio access uses the native web-apis: [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext), [Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator), [MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices), [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder). The key lines of code are below:

```js
// getting list of all AUDIO devices:
// const audioSources = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices({ audio: true }); 
// ^ above does NOT filter by audio only
const audioSources = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

//  creating a recorder object:
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const dest = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();  

const audioParams = {
  deviceId: "6e5fc2d7ffa5c6c04e06d282a5aa743e983e585a7e12118c80c0cd8646cce4b7", // this ID is from  audioSources object
}
const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: audioParams });
const audioIn = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);
audioIn.connect(dest);

const audioOptions = {
    bitsPerSecond:   128000,
    mimeType:       'audio/webm; codecs=opus',
};

const recorder = new MediaRecorder(dest.stream, audioOptions);
```

Because `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` does not take parameters, such as `{ audio: true }`, `enumerateDevices()` triggers the camera request.

I use the results of `enumerateDevices()` to access the device ID, which is then passed into `.getUserMedia()` to select the specific device. This allows users to select one or more audio inputs for the same recording.

**Is there a way of just querying available media for audio devices / excluding video?**

**Is there another way of identifiying all available audio devices?**

**How else can I select what device `.getUserMedia()` returns as a stream?**

The only existing information I could find on this was on the shut-down Atom Community forum:
[Electron keeps accessing my webcam for NO REASON](https://discuss.atom.io/t/electron-keeps-accessing-my-webcam-for-no-reason/78144) - two developers discovering the same behaviour in Sept'20 with different Antivirus software. No resolution.

Originally seen using Electron 8.5.0. Issue remains after updating to 13.1.2

**Software versions:** Electron 13.1.2, ESET 14.2.10.0

Comment: All the documentation I've seen for `enumerateDevices` indicates that it doesn't take an argument, so it would be enumerating video devices too. Can you get by with just `getUserMedia({ audio: true})` instead of specifying a device ID?

Comment: Confirming your comment about ```enumerateDevices```. No parameters. All devices (including video) are returned.  - great spot. Found the object I retained had been filtered to just audio by my own code!

Comment: I assume it is the "default" audio device returned from ```getUserMedia({ audio: true})```? I use my result of ```enumerateDevices``` to allow users to select one or more of the available audio channels when recording (e.g. Internal Mic, Other Mic, Stereo Mix) to record. I then pass the ID from  ```enumerateDevices``` into ```getUserMedia({ audio: deviceId})``` to get the audio from the specific device. I can record multiple audio input devices into a single output. Do you know any another ways of identifying or specifying the mics available?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any.