# When trying to convert an array of audio blobs into one, the combined blob only saves the first blob in the array

Tags: javascript, audio, blob, mediarecorder

I am creating an audio recording using mediaRecorder.
I start recording like so:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
        mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/wav';
        mediaRecorder.audioChannels = 1;

        mediaRecorder.start();
```

After starting, I am using the onDataAvailable function to push each audio chunk to an array:

```
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
            recordedBlobs.push(blob);
            wavesurfer.loadBlob(blob);
        };
```

when the recording stops, I try to combine all the chunks to one blob:

```
let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'audio/wav'});
```

but when I try to play the `recordedBlob` I only get the contents of the first blob in the array.
When I try to play each individual blob in the array, together they do in fact contain the entire audio recording, so that means that the problem has to be with the way I combine them using the blob constructor as shown above.
Can anyone help me see where I went wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly in your code do you know when the recording is complete? Have you verified the length of your array at the point you try to construct the combined blob?

Comment: the user clicks the stop button, and then I stop the recording with mediaRecorder.stop();
I have indeed verified the length of the array, and as I said in the post when I play each chuck individually and in a row, the whole recording plays out fine, but I still want to convert it to one audio file.

Comment: Right, well the behavior you're describing would make sense if the attempt to make and play the combined blob happened prematurely, before all the data available events had happened.

Comment: I agree, I couldn't figure it out so that is why I went to ask here

Comment: I could be wrong, but wouldn't each blob contain some information about the data, aka some sort of header. So, when you combine them the "header" not updated?
Maybe answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165335/how-do-you-combine-many-audio-tracks-into-one-for-mediarecorder-api) question could help.

Comment: I ended up using an alternative javascript package for recording